# JMeter test plan for 100 users making 20 different http requests simultaneously

Tags: jmeter

What I have tried so far

Creating 100 Thread Groups which  has 20 different HTTP Request listeners each,
so total 100*20 => 2000 unique different http requests..

Each Thread Group configured with

Number of Threads =  1

Ramp-up Period = 0

For Test Plan **Unchecked** Run Thread Groups Consecutively

**Problem**: Total 2000 requests are making in span of 10 - 20 seconds, but I want to make the all requests
simultaneously, or at least in span of 1-2 seconds is ok

Comment: I tried Parallel HTTP request sampler plugin, but in listeners it showing combined  sample time of 20 requests, but I need individual request response time

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your HTTP Request samplers under a single [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), you don't need to have different Thread Groups with 1 user (or at least going forward consider using [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) to avoid code duplication)
2. Add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) at the same level with HTTP Request samplers and set `Number of Simulated Users to Group by` to `20`

   [image]

Comment: But I need that http requests to be different for each user, typically 100 users making 20 http requests, so total 2000 unique different http requests making simultaneously  or in span of 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Threads are supposed to bring you concurrency, not ThreadGroups. Those are meant to model different user behaviours.

Please try 1 ThreadGroup with 100 Threads.

Depending on what exactly your use case is, you could then put all the listeners into one Random Controller inside the ThreadGroup. Our you could use any other controllers that suit your needs.